# ¿Evento click en javascript no responde a la primera en responsive?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Avanzando poco a poco en esta pagina web, con el tema de la función con dispositivos móviles, pensé que en esta parte ya lo tenia listo prácticamente, pero a la vez salen pequeños detalles en este caso sigo el con navbar, me percate que en modo responsivo al dar click la primera vez en alguna opción o item no hace caso el evento, así mismo cuando refresco la pagina en el dispositivo, cuando volver dar click por segunda vez el evento ya responde y se me oculta como debe de ser.

```js
function cerrar() {
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link:not(.servic)'); 
    const menuToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent'); 
    const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle: false}); 
    navLinks.forEach( function(l) { l.addEventListener('click', function() 
    {  if (menuToggle.classList.contains('show')) { bsCollapse.toggle(); } }) ; });
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

/* NAVBAR*/
.dropdown-menu{
  border: 0;
  text-align: left !important;
   right: auto !important;
}


.nav-item{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  margin-right: 30px; 
}
.dropdown-item{
  color: rgb(247, 250, 250);;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}

#informacion{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion" onclick="cerrar()">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#producto" onclick="cerrar()">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdownMenu">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle servic" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Servicios</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"  style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">VENTAS</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">TRANSPORTE</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="cerrar()">MAYOREO</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<!-- DATOS DE INFORMACIÓN -->

    <section id="informacion">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>
      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
        
        Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
        <br>
        ¿Por qué lo usamos?
        
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
         </p>
     </div> 
    </section>

   
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/cerrar.js"> </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás teniendo es que tus 'listeners'/'escuchas' no se cargan hasta que no se ejecuta la función 'cerrar()' que viendo tu problema es totalmente innecesaria, por eso la eliminé de todo el código y su funcionamiento lo delegué al contexto global para que se ejecute apenas se inicie el script.

De esta manera, tu código adquiere ya toda la funcionalidad deseada.

```js
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link:not(.servic)'); 
const menuToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent'); 
const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle, {toggle: false}); 
navLinks.forEach( function(l) { l.addEventListener('click', function() 
{  if (menuToggle.classList.contains('show')) { bsCollapse.toggle(); } }) ; });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

/* NAVBAR*/
.dropdown-menu{
  border: 0;
  text-align: left !important;
   right: auto !important;
}


.nav-item{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
  margin-right: 30px; 
}
.dropdown-item{
  color: rgb(247, 250, 250);;
  font-size: 14px;
  
}

#informacion{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-WJUUqfoMmnfkBLne5uxXj+na/c7sesSJ32gI7GfCk4zO4GthUKhSEGyvQ839BC51" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stilos.css" />
    <title>Slider</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top navbar-dark" style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LEDESMA</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#informacion">Conócenos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#producto">Producto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdownMenu">
            <a class="nav-link active dropdown-toggle servic" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Servicios</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"  style="background: rgb(40, 82, 114)">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">VENTAS</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TRANSPORTE</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">MAYOREO</a></li> 
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<!-- DATOS DE INFORMACIÓN -->

    <section id="informacion">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Información</h1>
      <p>
        ¿Qué es Lorem Ipsum?
        
        Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen. No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.
        <br>
        ¿Por qué lo usamos?
        
        Es un hecho establecido hace demasiado tiempo que un lector se distraerá con el contenido del texto de un sitio mientras que mira su diseño. El punto de usar Lorem Ipsum es que tiene una distribución más o menos normal de las letras, al contrario de usar textos como por ejemplo "Contenido aquí, contenido aquí". Estos textos hacen parecerlo un español que se puede leer. Muchos paquetes de autoedición y editores de páginas web usan el Lorem Ipsum como su texto por defecto, y al hacer una búsqueda de "Lorem Ipsum" va a dar por resultado muchos sitios web que usan este texto si se encuentran en estado de desarrollo. Muchas versiones han evolucionado a través de los años, algunas veces por accidente, otras veces a propósito (por ejemplo insertándole humor y cosas por el estilo).
         </p>
     </div> 
    </section>

   
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta amigo, voy a validarlo porque también tengo creado otro archivo javascript para cerrar los submenus desplegables del item de servicios.